# trying to use d3js with angularJS. try to append a svg to html but its not added

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, svg

im trying to use d3js combined with angularJS. But if i try to append a svg to my html file, i get d3 is not found and the svg is not added.

**Javascript file**

```
var w = 950,
      h = 800,
      data = [20, 30, 40];

var svg = d3.select("#test")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

console.log(svg);
```

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.45.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

if i look into console, the svg should be added. but its not :(
do somebody knows why? and could help me?
here is the code if you want to see it not working.
http://plnkr.co/edit/vrDCmFCK0iwsxf9Ux0uA

Comment: you're mixing html (the main document) with https (all the resources). Pick one or the other.

Comment: thanks but it dosn't fix that the svg isn't added to the html file.

Comment: the plunker works for me with that change.

Comment: not for me =/ you should get in console an output with 2 arrays. in the first should be a svg added. but its not :(

Comment: That's what I get with Firefox on a Mac.